# PHP with SQL wildcard search

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP I have a function to return results for a search form.

```
function search($search)    {
global $database;
$search2 = ( '%' . $search[0] . $search[1] . $search[2] . $search[3] . '%' );
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE is_approved = 1 
AND (city LIKE '$search' 
OR     state LIKE '$search' 
OR state LIKE '$search2' 
OR 'city' LIKE '$search2')";

$matches = $database ->query($q1);
return $matches;
}
```

The search2 variable is meant to wildcard search for four character matches in the location such as 'Cinc' matching 'Cincinnati'. To do this the query needs a wildcard with the % character before and after.

Whenever I run the query directly in MYSQL to test it, it works fine. Whenever I run this in the PHP code the wildcard portion doesn't seem to be working. If I echo %search2 as in my example, $search2 will echo %Cinc% which is what I presume it should be for a wildcard search. Why are no results returned for the wildcard portion?

Comment: Can you output the full query?

Comment: where are you fetching your query? like is there a fetchAll in `query` function?

Comment: it might be the case the `query` function is sanitizing your query string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're literally generating an SQL search string that looks like

```
WHERE something LIKE '%foobarbaz%'
```

This will ONLY match fields where the field literally contains the exact string `foobarbaz` somewhere within it. If you want to search for the individual words `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, you need

```
WHERE something like '%foo%' OR something like '%bar%' OR something LIKE '%baz%'
```

For multiple words, this gets very ugly very fast, and using `%..%` wildcards also prevents the use of indexes, meaning your query is going to be forcing a full table scan every time it executes.

You should probably look into using a [FULLTEXT index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead, which would reduce your query too

```
WHERE MATCH (something) AGAINST ('foo bar baz')
```

WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$search2 = '%'.$search[0],$search[1],$search[2],$search[3].'%';
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE is_approved = 1 
AND (city LIKE '".$search."'
OR   state LIKE '".$search."' 
OR   state LIKE '".$search2."'
OR   city LIKE '".$search2."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting helped me spot it and I removed the single quote from 'city' in the query and it worked perfectly. It might be PHP parsing the single quote.

The original query

```
SELECT * FROM tournaments 
WHERE is_approved = 1 
AND (city LIKE '$search' 
OR state LIKE '$search' 
OR state LIKE '$search2' 
OR 'city' LIKE '$search2')
```

as opposed to

```
SELECT * FROM tournaments 
WHERE is_approved = 1 
AND (city LIKE '$search' 
OR state LIKE '$search' 
OR state LIKE '$search2' 
OR city LIKE '$search2')
```